# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </span>; expected </br>

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

I created the stub classes using CXF wsdl2java tool. 
I am using Apache CXF library, with JCIFS. I validated the WSDL file itself through couple tools, it is good. Here is the code. It looks like some setting I must do.

**//JCIFS Authentication related code**

```
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "NTS");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", "ecmchat.mark.gov");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "300000"); // 5 minutes
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.cachePolicy", "1200"); // 20 minutes
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", "user");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", "password");

//Register the jcifs URL handler to enable NTLM
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
```

**//WSDL and Client settings**

```
URL wsdlURL = BF.WSDL_LOCATION;
if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) {
    File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
    try {
        if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
            wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
        } else {
            wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

BF ss = new BF(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
BFSoap port = ss.getBFSoap12();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();

httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(32000);

http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

**// Calling the method**

```
System.out.println("Invoking testMethod...");
String _testMethod__return = port.testMethod();
System.out.println("testMethod.result=" + _testMethod__return);
```

I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </span>; expected </br>.
 at [row,col,system-id]: [59,22,"https://ecmchat.mark.gov/BF/BF.asmx"]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:621)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:491)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:475)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.reportWrongEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3365)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3292)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2911)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1123)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1361)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1255)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1183)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:235)
    ... 9 more
```

If I comment out the JCIFS NTLM authentication code, I get a HTTP 401 error. Therefore, I believe, at least it is passing some kind of authorization step.

And, if I use local WSDL in place of remote URL WSDL, then I get a different error like "method not implemented" on the call to the method. May be this is due to me not using the local WSDL correctly. I do not even know if we can use the local WSDL reference for remote service.

Then, I created a SoapUI dummy service with this WSDL, and the same code (but without the JCIFS authentication code) works good, and successfully calls the methods.

It appears to me that I must add some more appropriate settings in the configuration related code. 
Am I right, and are you aware of any, for NTLM authentication and Apache CXF?

**But parsing error is confusing???**

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is related. 
My original WSDL URL that I gave was this.
https://ecmchat.mark.gov/BF/BF.asmx
I added a ?wsdl like below
https://ecmchat.mark.gov/BF/BF.asmx?wsdl
Then I am getting a different error.

**I wonder why it is working if I access my local SoapUI version of the same WSDL service, but not for the remote one.**

```
Invoking testMethod...
Jan 07, 2020 10:47:25 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {https://ecmchat.mark.gov}BF#{https://ecmchat.mark.gov}testMethod has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not implemented.
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.openConnection(URLStreamHandler.java:96)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1028)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.https.HttpsURLConnectionFactory.createConnection(HttpsURLConnectionFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.createConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.setupConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:125)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:505)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.testMethod(Unknown Source)
    at edison.learn.BFSoap_BFSoap12_Client.main(BFSoap_BFSoap12_Client.java:90)

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Method not implemented.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.testMethod(Unknown Source)
    at edison.learn.BFSoap_BFSoap12_Client.main(BFSoap_BFSoap12_Client.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not implemented.
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.openConnection(URLStreamHandler.java:96)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1028)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.https.HttpsURLConnectionFactory.createConnection(HttpsURLConnectionFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.createConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.setupConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:125)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:505)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
    ... 2 more
```